# Hover tooltip in Shiny using pure ggplot2 solution

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

The goal here is to render a tooltip on hover using a pure *ggplot2* solution without any plotly of javascript hacks.

Here is a naive tentative solution (that does not work)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage( 
    plotOutput("plotCars", hover="hover", width=700,height=300), 
    verbatimTextOutput("info")), 
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    hovered <- reactive(nearPoints(mtcars, input$hover, maxpoints = 1) %>%
                           rownames_to_column("model"))

    output$plotCars <- renderPlot({ 
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_point(color="red",data=hovered()) +
      geom_label(aes(label=model),data=hovered(),
                 hjust="inward",vjust="inward",
                 size=4,color="red",alpha=0.5)+
      xlab("Weight(1000 lbs)")+ylab("Miles/gallon")
    })
    
    output$info <- renderPrint({
      hovered()
    })
})
```

The problem here is that as soon as the plot is re-rendered including the hover information (e.g. a label), the hover event is automatically reset to `NULL`, thus invalidating the plot.

[image: Example of hover tooltip with naive solution]

In practice the above solution *almost* works, the tooltip for the hovered point is briefly shown, but immediately the `input$hover` event is invalidated by the new plot and the re-rendering of the plot removed the tooltip since a that point the hover event is now `NULL`. In fact the tooltip blinks once and then disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to keep the previous value of the hovered data point avoiding the invalidation. This objective can be achieved using the [`observeEvent()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/observeEvent.html) method and a [`reactiveVal()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.7.0/reactiveVal.html). The solution works like this:

- the hovered point information is a reactive value (`reactiveVal()`), initialized with a zero-row tibble with the same columns as the plotted data set.
  This initial value allow a smooth visualization in a ggplot2 layer, that would not be possible initializing it to `NULL`.
- the value is updated in response to an hover event, the function `observeEvent()` by default ignores when an event become `NULL` (*`ignoreNULL = TRUE`*), therefore when the `input$hover` is invalidated to `NULL` the value is not updated and remain the same as before
- in the plot rendering, the `hovered()` value is initially a zero-row tibble (but still having the right columns to be compatible with the plot default data) thus not showing anything, later when an hover near a point is performed it will contain the point information.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage( 
    plotOutput("plotCars", hover="hover", width=700,height=300), 
    verbatimTextOutput("info")), 
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    hovered <- reactiveVal(mtcars %>% filter(FALSE) %>% rownames_to_column("model"))
    observeEvent(input$hover, {
                 hovered(nearPoints(mtcars, input$hover, maxpoints = 1) %>%
                           rownames_to_column("model"))
    })
    
    output$plotCars <- renderPlot({ 
      ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + 
      geom_point() +
      geom_point(color="red",data=hovered()) +
      geom_label(aes(label=model),data=hovered(),
                 hjust="inward",vjust="inward",
                 size=4,color="red",alpha=0.5)+
        xlab("Weight(1000 lbs)")+ylab("Miles/gallon")
    })
    
    output$info <- renderPrint({
      hovered()
    })
  })
```